# OpenTK mouse hover animated effect

Tags: c#, opentk

I’m using OpenTK for 2D, and I want a .png object on the screen to have a smooth grow/shrink hover animation based on whether the mouse button is on top of the png object.

The equivalent of this in CSS would be the “transition: size 300ms”. What mathematical function should be used to make the hover animation smooth, and how should I change the size of the png object according to that function frame by frame?

Is there an easier approach?

Thanks!